# Filter logic with multiple conditions and depths

Tags: filters

I am creating a report which must be match the following:

```
Type = Minor Works AND
(Stage: 05 OR 06 AND Stage Age >= 5) OR (Stage: 07 AND Stage Age >= 10)
```

This is the filter I have created with the following logic but I recieve the following error:

> Your filter must use parentheses around successive AND and OR expressions.

Here is the filter:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I can't tell if you need to use

```
 1 AND ((2 OR (3 AND 5)) OR (4 AND 6))
```

or

```
1 AND (((2 OR 3) AND 5) OR (4 AND 6))
```

but one of those should work for you.

Comment: The second formula was the one I needed. However you got the last conditions wrong it should be  (4 AND 6), the current formula will return an error because condition 6 isnt called.

Comment: edited to use condition 6